# Trouble running Python 2.7 in Atom. "Unable to find command: python"

Tags: python, atom-editor

I'm currently trying to migrate to Atom to use as a code editor for python at home.

After following tutorials on how to set this up I have installed the packages atom-runner and script.

I tried running it and got the following error message:

[image: Screengrab]

[image: Error Message]

I've looked into what and where the path is exactly and how to correct it but I haven't found any sufficent explanation.
How do I fix it?

So I know how to make the PYTHONPATH variable except I don't know what the value should be. How do I determine the value?

Comment: can you type "python" in a standard command window and will it run from there?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Typing in "python" gets: 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: You need to set the directory where python is in your system `PATH` (not `PYTHONPATH` which is for modules)

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Thank you! This has fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a path to python binaries in the system `PATH`. This question has everything you need to fix your issue: <del>[How to add to the pythonpath in windows 7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7)</del> [How To Add Python to the Windows Path](https://superuser.com/questions/143119/how-to-add-python-to-the-windows-path)

Comment: it's not a pythonpath problem, it's a simple path problem. python is not running yet.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Indeed, this one is correct